# Property 'option' does not exist on type 'CreateOptionActionMeta'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm using the CreatableSelect component from react-selects in my Typescript project but I'm facing this types issue as seen below.

[image]

My CreatableSelect component looks like this:

```
<CreatableSelect
  isMulti
  isLoading={isLoading}
  getNewOptionData={(value, label) => ({
    value: slugify(value),
    label,
  })}
  onChange={(selectedValues, actionMeta) => {
    onFoodsSelectChange(selectedValues, actionMeta);
  }}
  options={options}
  value={selected}
/>
```

and according to [the documentation](https://react-select.com/props#creatable-props), the `getNewOptionData` "Returns the data for the new option when it is created. Used to display the value, and **is passed to onChange.**". However, the [types for `'create-option'`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-select/src/types.d.ts#L95-L98) action doesn't include the `option` passed in by `getNewOptionData`.

Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be just a wrong type definitions for `create-option` action meta. But while `CreateOptionActionMeta` *type* does not have an `option` field it's runtime value has it. And also it is accessible as the last element of `selectedValues` argument.

So, you can just ignore wrong typings and assert typescript that you know better:

```ts
type FoodOption = { value: string, label: string }

const onFoodsSelectChange = (
    selectedValues: OptionsType<FoodOption>,
    actionMeta: ActionMeta<FoodOption>
) => {
    switch (actionMeta.action) {
        case 'create-option': {
            const option = (actionMeta as unknown as { option: FoodOption }).option
            ...
```

Or use the last element of the `selectedValues`:

```ts
const onFoodsSelectChange = (
    selectedValues: OptionsType<FoodOption>,
    actionMeta: ActionMeta<FoodOption>
) => {
    switch (actionMeta.action) {
        case 'create-option': {
            const [option] = selectedValues.slice(-1)
            ...
```

Comment: Using the last element of selectedValues is a good tip! This also made the `getNewOptionData` prop redundant so lesser lines. I think this might be a type design flaw but oh well. Thanks @aleksxor!